# My Bot Gives role to a mentioned user in a message

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

ok so when another bot in my server sends a message which contains a user mention, my bot should give a role to that mentioned user. I dont know how to do it but i tried doin something with an event and gives errors. Pls help(I'm rookie in python)

**my code**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    Role = discord.utils.get(msg.guild.roles, name='level 2') 
    if msg.content.find("advanced to level 2")!=-1:
        await msg.user.mention.add_roles(Role)
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Also `msg.user.mention` is a string. You want to add the role to the `user` and not the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `msg.mentions[0]` to get the mentioned user and check if the author is a bot

Below is the revised code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    Role = discord.utils.get(msg.guild.roles, name='level 2') 
    if msg.content.find("advanced to level 2")!=-1 and msg.author.bot:
        await msg.mentions[0].add_roles(Role)
```